# Page previous in Detail View for Detail View - Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I'm have a page Detail View with a button with link for Detail View. But like the url need a PK, i cannot set PK per be a Detail View. How can I define a url for the previous page without the PK ?

In **Template**

`<button id="botaoVoltar" type="submit" class="mb-10 btn btn-light"><a href="{% url 'relatorio' ???  %}">Voltar</a>  </button>`

In **urls**

```
path('relatorios/relatorio/<int:pk>', RelatorioView.as_view(), name='relatorio')
```

Exception:

```
NoReverseMatch Exception Value:  
Reverse for 'relatorio' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['relatorios/relatorio/(?P[0-9]+)$']
```

Comment: Can you share your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a method to look up the previous object:

```
class RelatorioView(DetailView):
    # …
    def get_previous(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(
            pk__lt=self.object.pk
        ).order_by('-pk').first()
```

Next we can use that to obtain the previous one:

```
{% with prev=view.get_previous %}
{% if prev %}
    <button id="botaoVoltar" type="submit" class="mb-10 btn btn-light">
        <a href="{% url 'relatorio' prev.pk %}">Voltar</a>
    </button>
{% endif %}
```